# jquery load another jquery when button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have special situation where I need to load the script when a button pressed, not when the page load

my button has `copySurName` as ID
in my script I have this:

```
$("#copySurName").click(function () {
});
```

in that script, I need to load a script called `CopyingScript` exists in `Script` folder in the server

I am using asp.net

#### Edit

This is the script that I need to load

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('button#copySurName').zclip({
        path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $("td:contains('Surname')").next('td').text()
    });

});
```

Please notice that this script has a `document.ready` function, that doesn't make mistakes, right?

Comment: Why not load them both and only trigger the actions you care about on demand? Dynamic loading of javascript files is not a recommended practice and will detract from the overall UX.

Comment: @ChristianDuvall because the script is working on ID that is not exist when the page load, so in this case, i am loosing the css for the page

Comment: Don't perform the event assignment on document ready, perform the assignment when you know you're in the correct workflow.

Also, $('#copySurName') is faster than $('button#copySurName') for selection.

Comment: sure enough, zeroClipboard doesn't work on dynamic elements until they are actually inserted, but why not just add the code inside the click event handler, why load another file ?

Comment: @adeneo that is a great idea, tell me please how to do that

Comment: @adeneo I just got what you are talking about , I tried that, but not working

Comment: @adeneo I also but alert in the on click, the alert works, but the copying not

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('button#copySurName').zclip({
        path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $("td:contains('Surname')").next('td').text()
    });

});
```

in a separate `.js` file.

And then do this:

```
$("#copySurName").click(function () {
   $.getScript('path to the script file'); // loads the script and executes it
});
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)