# css not applied when load the page with id not exist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have this script

```
$('button#copySurName').zclip({
            path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: $("td:contains('Surname')").next('td').text()
        });
```

which needs to be loaded when the page load.

when the page loads, it doesn't have the id `copySurName`,

so for something I don't know, the css is not applied to the page,

when I remove the `script` that loads that script, the css working good.

you may say that I use on click on that button, it won't work because that script needs to be loading when the page loads

Comment: how are you setting the style? if you're setting it using javascript it might not work with the error on page

Comment: It's not a style, it's zeroClipboard, and it inserts a flash movie at the location of the element, there is no way to do this on a dynamic element that isn't there yet, you have to run that code when the element is actually there.

Comment: It's also a duplicate of [jquery load another jquery when button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743752/jquery-load-another-jquery-when-button-click)